# circular array around an empty as origin is not workin

Tags: mesh, modifiers

circular array around an empty as origin is not working out for me can u guys pls help me out I've attached the image[image] below

Comment: Make sure the empty and the mesh object share the same origin

Comment: tried it, actually in the image above both share the same origin point

Comment: empty as an origin to object

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of the array modifier fields ?

Comment: I don't know but I just apply only rotation to both empty and the target object  and  ju it was fine

Comment: thanks anyway man @Gorgious